# Nested Dictionary vs. JSON file for python library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Excel workbook where each tab has information on a file type. I'd like the info to be accessible to a python package that I am going to write. I’m debating whether I should hard-code each tab as key/values in a nested dictionary or make each tab a JSON file that the library would then read in. Which is considered a best practice and why?

It would be about 20 files vs. 20 keys. Each key would then have about 40 key-value pairs.

Example of the dictionary:

```
files = OrderedDict([
                    ('txt',
                        {
                            'default program': 'Notepad',
                            'Comes with Windows': True,
                           ...

                        }
                     ),
                      ('doc',
                        {
                            'default program': 'Word',
                            'Comes with Windows': True,
                           ...

                        }
                     )
                ])
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the existing python packages to work with excel?   Some of the popular ones are [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/), [xlsswriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/), and [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/)

Comment: it's just hardcoded information that someone provided to me in Excel. I would want it be either be hardcoded into my library or broken out in JSON files. I don't want to stick with Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd use JSON since it's just as easy to work with as dictionaries (in my opinion) and is certainly more standard than saving data in the form of dictionaries. In addition, if you intend to be updating this data, JSON would certainly be the way to go.

EDIT: I'd also consider it to be somewhat messy to be hard-coding large dictionaries into your code.

Comment: so would I then have the package always read in the JSON or only as part of a method call? For example, if the user wants to know if .doc is a standard windows file type

Comment: I would load the JSON every time that the package is loaded, personally. Just store it in a variable unless you consider it too large to be kept in RAM. If you intend to not change the data at all, then hard-coding _is_ still an option, as I implied.